# Can I use TensorBoard also with jupyter notebooks

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I am experimenting (learning) TensorBoard and use the following code I got from the internet (simple regression function)

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
#sess = tf.InteractiveSession()  #define a session
# Create 100 phony x, y data points in NumPy, y = x * 0.1 + 0.3
x_data = np.random.rand(100).astype("float32")
y_data = x_data * 0.1 + 0.3

# Try to find values for W and b that compute y_data = W * x_data + b
# (We know that W should be 0.1 and b 0.3, but Tensorflow will
# figure that out for us.)
with tf.name_scope("calculatematmul") as scope:
    W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1], -1.0, 1.0))
    b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))
    y = W * x_data + b

# Minimize the mean squared errors.
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y - y_data))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

# Before starting, initialize the variables.  We will 'run' this first.
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

# Launch the graph.
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

#### ----> ADD THIS LINE <---- ####
writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter('mnist_logs', sess.graph_def)

# Fit the line.
for step in xrange(201):
    sess.run(train)
    if step % 20 == 0:
        print(step, sess.run(W), sess.run(b))
```

The code runs fine when I create a python file and run the file with

```
python test.py
```

also it runs fine in the jupyter notebook

However, while Tensorboard gets the information from running the python file (that is to say, it creates the xyz....home file), the interactive version does not create any info usable for Tensorboard.

Can somebody explain to me why, please!

Thanks
Peter

Comment: Does it create event files? Also, if it puts event files into "somedirectory/mnist_logs", you need to start TensorBoard with logdir set to somedirectory, not somedirectory/mnist_logs

Comment: the notebook version does not create event files, even though the exact same code is used in both versions.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you use the full path when starting tensorboard.

```
tensorboard --logdir='./somedirectory/mnist_logs'
```